# Replace only certain double quotes in data file

Tags: linux, text-processing

We extract data from a database to a flat file, we use a pipe for column delimiter and double quotes for text delimiter.

Data file looks Something like this:

```
"164829" | "collection 1" | "wood plank 2" x 4" long" | "23.5" 
"2017"|"S"|"221318"|"WE"|"20170118"|"Someones name"|"20170215"|"1785"|"009"|"20170215"|"182339"|"99536"|"00090"|"LOCAL00"|"930N"|"2017"|"6100"|"0000880"|1.000|0.000|"EA"|" "|" "|" "|" "|"005"|"00000000"|" "|" "|"1785"|"50228"|"R"|"2017"|"NMT CAUTION| 5" X 3" NAT ON BLK"|" "|" "|"USD"|"7444"|" "|"000"|"COIN"|"04"|35.00|"00"
```

What command/script could find every case where the data (not including the text delimiter) can be escaped with a second double quote?

The end result should look like this:

```
"164829" | "collection 1" | "wood plank 2"" x 4"" long" | "23.5"
"2017"|"S"|"221318"|"WE"|"20170118"|"Someones name"|"20170215"|"1785"|"009"|"20170215"|"182339"|"99536"|"00090"|"LOCAL00"|"930N"|"2017"|"6100"|"0000880"|1.000|0.000|"EA"|" "|" "|" "|" "|"005"|"00000000"|" "|" "|"1785"|"50228"|"R"|"2017"|"NMT CAUTION| 5"" X 3"" NAT ON BLK"|" "|" "|"USD"|"7444"|" "|"000"|"COIN"|"04"|35.00|"00"
```

Comment: What do you mean by escaping the data? Why not just use the pipe by itself as a delimiter as that would separate the text into each column just as a space, tab, or comma would? You are complicating things where it isn't necessary by using double quotes when you already have the pipe as a delimiter. If it's just text within a file then you don't need to escape it unless you are using a command such as `sed` to alter the file and need to work with the text on the command line. If that's the case, you can just escape it with backslashes or single quotes.

Comment: The pipe can be found within data as well ie “2433” | “Concatenate the fields with | in your summary” | “5’6” tall”

Comment: Hence we have to use column and text delimiters. I apolologize if my statement was t clear when I said escaping the data... I meant to say escaping the data which includes “ within the data.

Comment: We’re after a way to escape the text delimiter which in our this case is “ (our only choice for text delimiter) that is found in the data ie 5’6”

Comment: The pipe is already a delimiter for both of them. By its very definition, it separates all of the text into different columns.  I can understand why you need double quotes to specify height, width, and length but it really isn't necessary for the rest. Even when using double quotes to specify height, width, and length, the pipe acts as a delimiter for each field no matter what value or characters are contained inside which makes the other double quotes unnecessary and redundant. It's only a suggestion on my part as it would make your database a lot easier to manage.

Comment: The pipe | can be found within the data as well, that would throw off the import... so the double quotes " are necessary to escape that situation. It's very common for ETL files to have a column delimiter and a text delimiter. The problem in our case was that the text delimiter could be found within the data as well... so that needs to be escaped as well, for our purpose, escaping it with a second double quote takes care of the problem.

Comment: I don't mean to be condescending but your use of the term `delimiter` is rather off. A delimiter is used to separate columns. What you are doing with the quotes is escaping a special character and not separating columns. In your case, there's no reason to surround the contents of every column with quotes unless every column has a pipe in it. It may be better to use a tab as a delimiter instead of pipes but either way, the quotes in every column aren't needed and are just adding complications.

Comment: Just to help you out in the future, I suggest looking into Mysql instead of using a flat file database. It has its own delimiters built in so that don't have to worry about escaping characters anywhere near as much. That would help you to avoid this situation.

Comment: The question at hand was how to escape a double quote within the contents of a string (example given in the original question), in our case we're after adding an additional double quote to escape it. I appreciate your input, I really do, but your approach was "you're doing it wrong" which to be fair gave it some thought (you could be right) but unfortunately the facts didn't change - we need to escape a double quote within a file. It's not about disclosing why we're doing what we're doing - granted there's room in this forum for "why are you doing it that way?" etc. It's not the case here

Comment: In your defense, I may have used the term "delimiter" loosely... In my defense however, the example given in the original question was pretty clear. Before and After examples are the best! :)

Comment: I apologize if you took it as me stating that you're doing it wrong but that's not how I meant it. I was simply trying to help. If the answers given by others helped you with this issue then that's what's important. I'm only suggesting a RDBMS such as Mysql so that you don't have to worry about manually setting delimiters or escaping special characters as much. Perhaps you can't just migrate your production DB to a different system but I suggest trying it out as it is designed to make things run more smoothly by avoiding issues such as this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little tricky with just regular expressions, but it can be done in several steps. Here's the perl script that I used for this (sed can't be used because I used lookaheads):

```
perl -pe 's/(?:(?:\||^)[ ]*"(.*?)\"[ ]*(?=\||$))/~~\1~~/gm;s/"/""/g;s/~~(.*?)~~/~~"\1"~~/g;s/~~~~/|/g;s/~~//g' inputfile.txt
```

(use `perl -pi -e` if you want to edit the input file)

The script does the following steps:

1. Look for everything that either is inside of |"{...}"|, (start of line)"{...}"|, or |"{...}"(end of line), ignoring spaces outside of the text. Replace the outside bits with `~~` (I used something that is known not to be inside of the text)
2. Replace all remaining quotation marks with doubled-up ones
3. Replace all internal `~~{...}~~` sequences with `~~"{...}"~~`
4. Replace all `~~~~` sequences (which will all be internal) to `|`
5. Remove all remaining `~~` sequences (which will be at the beginning and end of the lines)

Running each step given the following test text:

```
"164829" | "collection 1" | "wood plank 2" x 4" long" | "23.5"
"939485"|"collect "name""|"more items with | " and ""|"294.5""
```

We get the following output after each step:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?:(?:\||^)[ ]*"(.*?)\"[ ]*(?=\||$))/~~\1~~/gm;' testinput.txt                       
~~164829~~~~collection 1~~~~wood plank 2" x 4" long~~~~23.5~~
~~939485~~~~collect "name"~~~~more items with | " and "~~~~294.5"~~

$ perl -pe 's/(?:(?:\||^)[ ]*"(.*?)\"[ ]*(?=\||$))/~~\1~~/gm;s/"/""/g;' testinput.txt
~~164829~~~~collection 1~~~~wood plank 2"" x 4"" long~~~~23.5~~
~~939485~~~~collect ""name""~~~~more items with | "" and ""~~~~294.5""~~

$ perl -pe 's/(?:(?:\||^)[ ]*"(.*?)\"[ ]*(?=\||$))/~~\1~~/gm;s/"/""/g;s/~~(.*?)~~/~~"\1"~~/g;' testinput.txt
~~"164829"~~~~"collection 1"~~~~"wood plank 2"" x 4"" long"~~~~"23.5"~~
~~"939485"~~~~"collect ""name"""~~~~"more items with | "" and """~~~~"294.5"""~~

$ perl -pe 's/(?:(?:\||^)[ ]*"(.*?)\"[ ]*(?=\||$))/~~\1~~/gm;s/"/""/g;s/~~(.*?)~~/~~"\1"~~/g;s/~~~~/|/g;' testinput.txt
~~"164829"|"collection 1"|"wood plank 2"" x 4"" long"|"23.5"~~
~~"939485"|"collect ""name"""|"more items with | "" and """|"294.5"""~~

$ perl -pe 's/(?:(?:\||^)[ ]*"(.*?)\"[ ]*(?=\||$))/~~\1~~/gm;s/"/""/g;s/~~(.*?)~~/~~"\1"~~/g;s/~~~~/|/g;s/~~//g' testpipe.txt
"164829"|"collection 1"|"wood plank 2"" x 4"" long"|"23.5"
"939485"|"collect ""name"""|"more items with | "" and """|"294.5"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Input -

```
 "2017"|"S"|"221318"|"WE"|"20170118"|"Someones name"|"20170215"|"1785"|"009"|"20170215"|"182339"|"99536"|"00090"|"LOCAL00"|"930N"|"2017"|"6100"|"0000880"|1.000|0.000|"EA"|" "|" "|" "|" "|"005"|"00000000"|" "|" "|"1785"|"50228"|"R"|"2017"|"NMT CAUTION| 5" X 3" NAT ON BLK"|" "|" "|"USD"|"7444"|" "|"000"|"COIN"|"04"|35.00|"00"
```

CMD:

```
  awk -v RS='[[:blank:]]*[[:blank:]]*[|][[:blank:]]*|[[:blank:]]*[\n][[:blank:]]*' '{ if ($0 !~ /(^"([^"]|"")*"$)/) { gsub(/\"/,"\"\"");sub(/^"/,"");sub(/"$/,"") } printf "%s%s", $0, RT}' file.txt
```

Output  -

```
 "2017"|"S"|"221318"|"WE"|"20170118"|"Someones name"|"20170215"|"1785"|"009"|"20170215"|"182339"|"99536"|"00090"|"LOCAL00"|"930N"|"2017"|"6100"|"0000880"|1.000|0.000|"EA"|" "|" "|" "|" "|"005"|"00000000"|" "|" "|"1785"|"50228"|"R"|"2017"|"NMT CAUTION| 5"" X 3"" NAT ON BLK"|" "|" "|"USD"|"7444"|" "|"000"|"COIN"|"04"|35.00|"00"
```

Comment: Moved follow-up discussion to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75529/discussion-on-answer-by-bharat-replace-only-certain-double-quotes-in-data-file).

Comment: Bharat, it's working great for escaping pipes within text except for some unexpected quotes, here is a before: "2017"|"S"|"221318"|"WE"|"20170118"|"Someones name"|"20170215"|"1785"|"009"|"20170215"|"182339"|"99536"|"00090"|"LOCAL00"|"930N"|"2017"|"6100"|"0000880"|1.000|0.000|"EA"|" "|" "|" "|" "|"005"|"00000000"|" "|" "|"1785"|"50228"|"R"|"2017"|"NMT CAUTION| 5" X 3" NAT ON BLK"|" "|" "|"USD"|"7444"|" "|"000"|"COIN"|"04"|35.00|"00"

Comment: Here' s the after: "2017"|"S"|"221318"|"WE"|"20170118"|"Someones name"|"20170215"|"1785"|"009"|"20170215"|"182339"|"99536"|00090"|"LOCAL00"|"930N"|"2017"|"6100"|"00000880""|1.000|0.000|""EA"|" "|" "|" "|" "|"005" |"00000000"|" "|" "|"1785"|"50228"|"R"|"2017"|"NMT CAUTION| 5"" X 3"" NAT ON BLK"|" "|" "|"USD"|"7444"|" "|"000"| COIN"|"04""|35.00|""00"

Comment: Please notice the missing quote on |00090"|

Comment: please notice extra quote on |""EA"| and towards the end of the string at "04""|35.00|""00"

Comment: Its little difficult to predict unexpected quotes, but anyway lets try one more time, input and expected output please

Comment: Give it a try, hopefully should work, assuming there is no white space in beginning of lines ...

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Bharat. I've tested it and it appears to be working!! I'll run it against other data and post findings. Thanks again, much appreciated!

Comment: Bharat, thank you for all your effort. Your script provides a solution for anyone looking to "escape" a text qualifier, in our case a quote ("). Much appreciated, thanks again.

Comment: please update your question with  sample input including | and accept answers which you think is working, so that it could be useful to others

Answer (score 0):

Your double quote are not real double quote (“ vs ").
With real double quote " ,
You can try this sed (assume there is no @ in your data)

```
sed 's/" | "/@/g;s/"/""/g;s/^"//;s/"$//;s/@/" | "/g' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

Bahrat from this forum posted an answer that was very close to resolving the issue, somehow it was removed from this post (code below). The only issue is it cannot handle a pipe | within a string (ie "25"|"to concatenate data a | must be used"|"addendum 1"|20|"last entry") He was supposed to post today but the thread was deleted ??

```
awk -v FS='|' -v OFS='|' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){gsub(/"/,"\"\"",$i);sub(/"/,"",$i);sub(/"[^"]*$/,"",$i)}print}' myfile > myfile3
```